# Modifying a list in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Attempting to make list items clickable without a checkbox. I want those items to to get a strike through when clicked and still have the delete option at the end. This functions properly, but I can't seem to maintain that when I try to make the items clickable. How do I need to modify this code to make it work?

```
    <p class="lead" ng-bind="vm.list.content"></p>
  <div class="list-group">
    <span data-ng-repeat="item in vm.list.items|orderBy:'name'"
       class="list-group-item" ng-class="{strike: item.check}">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.check" ng-click="vm.cross(item)">
       <a class="btn btn-default pull-right" ng-click="vm.remove(item)">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" ng-bind="item.name + ' - ' + item.priority"></h4>
    </span>
  </div>
```

Controllers:

```
function remove(item){
  var removedItem = $scope.vm.list.items.indexOf(item);
  $scope.vm.list.items.splice(removedItem, 1);

  if (vm.list._id) {
    vm.list.$update(successCallback, errorCallback);
  } else {
    vm.list.$save(successCallback, errorCallback);
  }

        function successCallback(res) {
    $state.go('lists.view', {
      listId: res._id
    });
  }

  function errorCallback(res) {
    vm.error = res.data.message;}
}

function cross(item){

  if (vm.list._id) {
    vm.list.$update(successCallback, errorCallback);
  } else {
    vm.list.$save(successCallback, errorCallback);
  }

        function successCallback(res) {
    $state.go('lists.view', {
      listId: res._id
    });
  }

  function errorCallback(res) {
    vm.error = res.data.message;}
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the applicable controller code?

Comment: Specifically, cross() and remove().

Comment: `      function cross(item){
      
      
      if (vm.list._id) {
        vm.list.$update(successCallback, errorCallback);
      } else {
        vm.list.$save(successCallback, errorCallback);
      }

            function successCallback(res) {
        $state.go('lists.view', {
          listId: res._id
        });
      }

      function errorCallback(res) {
        vm.error = res.data.message;}
    }`

Comment: `function remove(item){
      var removedItem = $scope.vm.list.items.indexOf(item);
      $scope.vm.list.items.splice(removedItem, 1);
      
      if (vm.list._id) {
        vm.list.$update(successCallback, errorCallback);
      } else {
        vm.list.$save(successCallback, errorCallback);
      }

            function successCallback(res) {
        $state.go('lists.view', {
          listId: res._id
        });
      }

      function errorCallback(res) {
        vm.error = res.data.message;}
    }`

Comment: could you please add the code to your question instead of in comments?  it's very hard to read like that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to move the checkbox behavior to the item wrapper? In this case, if click on the trash, the outer click handler will not be triggered because we stop event from further propagation.

```
<div class="list-group">
    <span data-ng-repeat="item in vm.list.items|orderBy:'name'" class="list-group-item" ng-class="{strike: item.check}" ng-click="item.check = true; vm.cross(item)">
        <a class="btn btn-default pull-right" ng-click="vm.remove(item);$event.stopPropagation();">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
        </a>
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" ng-bind="item.name + ' - ' + item.priority"></h4>
    </span>
</div>
```

If you want to cross/uncross item by click, you can implement a method like toggleCross and use it instead of "item.check = true" statement:

```
item.toggleCheck = function() {
    this.check = !this.check;
}
```